# How to show “No Record Found” meassage in Table live search

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I would like to show to message "No record found." if there's no result in table after searching. this is example https://makitweb.com/how-to-live-search-on-the-html-table-with-jquery/

Jquery Code

```
$("#searchrec").keyup(function () {
        var input, filter, table, tr, td, i, txtValue;
        input = document.getElementById("searchrec");
        filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
        table = document.getElementById("detailTable");
        tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
        // Loop through all table rows, and hide those who don't match the search query

        $("#detailTable tr:not('.no-records')").filter(function () {
            for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
                td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[0];
                if (td)
                    txtValue = td.textContent || td.innerText;
                if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
                    tr[i].style.display = "";
                }
                else {
                    tr[i].style.display = "none";
                }
            }
            var trSel = $("#detailTable tr:not('.no-records'):visible");
            // Check for number of rows & append no records found row
            if (trSel.length == 0) {
                $("#detailTable").html('<tr class="no-records"><td colspan="3">No record found.</td></tr>');
            }
            else {
                $('.no-records').remove();
            }
        });

        //for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
        //    td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[0];
        //    if (td)
        //        txtValue = td.textContent || td.innerText;
        //    if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
        //        tr[i].style.display = "";
        //    }
        //    else {
        //        tr[i].style.display = "none";
        //    }
        //}

    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to avoid appending the **No records found** row to the table instead you can just show and hide that row.

I have updated your code and also added one **table-header** class to the heading row.

Try searching by name to see the results.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Live Search</title>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <style>
    .notfound {
      display: none;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <input type='text' id='searchrec' placeholder='Enter search text'>&nbsp;
  <!-- <input type='text' id='txt_name' placeholder='Enter search name'> -->
  <br />
  <table width='100%' border='1' id="detailTable" style='border-collapse:collapse;'>
    <thead>
      <tr class='table-heading'>
        <th>S.no</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Course</th>
        <th>City</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>

      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>Yogesh singh</td>
        <td>M.SC</td>
        <td>Bhopal</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>Sonarika Bhadoria</td>
        <td>BE</td>
        <td>Pune</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>Vishal Sahu</td>
        <td>BE</td>
        <td>Indore</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>Sunil Patel</td>
        <td>MBA</td>
        <td>Bhopal</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>Anil Singh</td>
        <td>MCA</td>
        <td>Delhi</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class='no-records' style="display: none;">
        <td colspan='4'>No record found</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>

  <!-- Script -->
  <script type='text/javascript'>
    $(document).ready(function () {
      $("#searchrec").keyup(function () {
        var input, filter, table, tr, td, i, txtValue;
        input = document.getElementById("searchrec");
        filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
        table = document.getElementById("detailTable");
        tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
        // Loop through all table rows, and hide those who don't match the search query

        $("#detailTable tr:not('.no-records')").filter(function () {
          for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
            td = $(tr[i]).find('td')[1];
            if (td) {
              txtValue = td.textContent || td.innerText;
              if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
                tr[i].style.display = "";
              }
              else {
                tr[i].style.display = "none";
              }
            }
          }
          var trSel = $("#detailTable tr:not('.no-records, .table-heading'):visible");
          // Check for number of rows & append no records found row
          if (trSel.length == 0) {

            $("#detailTable").find('.no-records').show();
          }
          else {
            $("#detailTable").find('.no-records').hide();
          }
        });


      });

    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Can you rearrange the code according to the code below?                                                                                
             for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
                td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[0];
                if (td)
                    txtValue = td.textContent || td.innerText;
                if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
                    tr[i].style.display = "";
                }
                else {
                    tr[i].style.display = "none";
                }
            }

Comment: @emre.senturk  tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[0]; this won't give you the table cell i.e td element. Correct way is use find method.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much for your reply. Can you rearrange the code according to the code below? I think it will be what I want.

```
$("#searchrec").keyup(function () {
        var input, filter, table, tr, td, i, txtValue;
        input = document.getElementById("searchrec");
        filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
        table = document.getElementById("detailTable");
        tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
        // Loop through all table rows, and hide those who don't match the search query

            for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
                td = $(tr[i]).find('td')[1];
                if (td) {
                    txtValue = td.textContent || td.innerText;
                    if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
                        tr[i].style.display = "";
                    }
                    else {
                        tr[i].style.display = "none";
                    }
                }
            }
            var trSel = $("#detailTable tr:not('.no-records'):visible");
            // Check for number of rows & append no records found row
            if (trSel.length == 0) {

                $("#detailTable").find('.no-records').show();
            }
            else {
                $("#detailTable").find('.no-records').hide();
            }
        });
```